# Floats in a csv are automatically rounded in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When I open a csv file in Python using Pandas, the float values of the last column are rounded.

```
ColA    Timestamp           Value             
1     06:40:00                 33.48     
2     06:29:00                 38.65          
3     07:05:00                 56.77  
4     06:43:00                 80.81   

ColA,"Timestamp","Value"
1,"06:40:00","33.48"
2,"06:29:00","38.65"
3,"07:05:00","56.77"
4,"06:43:00","80.81"
```

Instead I get:

```
ColA    Timestamp           Value             
1     06:40:00                 33     
2     06:29:00                 39          
3     07:05:00                 57  
4     06:43:00                 81
```

I simply used:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C://Users//me//Downloads//file.csv", delimiter = ",", float_precision="high")
```

I tried removing the last parameter, but nothing changes.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. What version of python and pandas are you using?

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava Python 3.7, Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: This also seems to work fine for me with Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.24.2. What do you get is you just do `print(df["Value"])`

Comment: @MattPitkin the type of the values is float64, I checked this, but no matter what I print (the whole csv, just the column etc), they are still rounded. Could there be a problem with the original csv?

Comment: Maybe. What happens if you copy the CSV text you've posted here into a new file and try reading that in?

Comment: If you explicitly print a value with 2 d.p., e.g., `print("{:.2f}".format(df["Value"][0]))` does it return the correct number? If it does then I'd guess you've somehow set something to only display floats as ints.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `read_csv` directly then typecast the column you want to explicitly become float.

```
df = pd.read_csv("C://Users//me//Downloads//file.csv")
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(float)

>>> df
   Col A Timestamp  Value
0      1  06:40:00  33.48
1      2  06:29:00  38.65
2      3  07:05:00  56.77
3      4  06:43:00  80.81
```